# Google Cloud Storage setting an expiry date on requested assets despite explicitly setting infinite TTL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, actionmailer

I have a Rails `5.2.3` app that's running on Google Cloud services, and I have some images that are user uploaded, such as staff images. These images are uploaded onto a GC Storage bucket set to be publicly accessible.

My current issue is that I'm trying to display these images inside of an email we send. In the email view, the image is being called as below. Note that employees are guaranteed to have an image present, we force users to upload employee photos, so there is no risk of one of these photos not existing.

```rb
<%= image_tag (employee.photo.service_url) if employee.photo.attached? %>
```

Now, the images actually show up fine in the emails... for 5 minutes, after which the images cease to be accessible, and visiting the image via the link present in the email takes us to a `404` with the file no longer existing. After taking a closer look at the image URL, I noticed a parameter, `Expires=` followed by a UNIX timestamp that translates to exactly 5 minutes after the email getting sent. I scoured every inch of our Google Cloud settings, and literally nowhere do I see anything about TTL or expiries or anything.

Here's an image of the url, as it's very long. I've redacted some project IDs and stuff like that, those aren't relevant

[image]

I think the issue is that I'm not accessing the public URL of the image in the bucket which *would* be permanent, as they say in the docs that you have to call the images with the `BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME` URL, but I can't use this because the images have randomized filenames once they're uploaded, and it's also not a very dynamic approach as we send these emails to every client, and every client has their own unique employees and employee images.

Here's a screenshot of the Storage bucket. As you can see, everything is Public, and manualy checking the images, I indeed see some of the staff images I've seen during testing.

[image]

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

My `storage.yml` file

```rb
google:
  service: GCS
  project: REDACTED
  credentials: <%= Rails.application.credentials.gcs_storage_credentials.to_json %>
  bucket: images-REDACTED
```

My `production.rb` environment file

```rb
config.active_storage.service = :google
config.action_mailer.asset_host = Rails.application.credentials.send(production_server_url)
```

My `Gemfile`

```rb
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'active_storage_base64'
gem 'google-cloud-storage', '~> 1.8', require: false
```

Comment: Can you share the way you obtain the image URL in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the url you attached, looks like you used a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

If my guess is correct, You can specify expires on your parameter.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#python-sample) to get detailed info about how to specify expire parameter.

It describes sample python code but you can adapt it your owns.

Below is some part of sample codes, I think this is what you want.

```
if query_parameters is None:
    query_parameters = dict()
query_parameters['X-Goog-Algorithm'] = 'GOOG4-RSA-SHA256'
query_parameters['X-Goog-Credential'] = credential
query_parameters['X-Goog-Date'] = request_timestamp
query_parameters['X-Goog-Expires'] = expiration
query_parameters['X-Goog-SignedHeaders'] = signed_headers
if subresource:
    query_parameters[subresource] = ''
```